# What is the most efficient way to adjust price during the minting of an ERC-721

Tags: erc-721, nft

We are creating an ERC-721 token that does through the standard minting procedure. I'm looking for a the most gas efficient way to adjust the price to a tiered system. We want the price to increase every 2000 minted.

Forgive me, I'm new to solidity and gas considerations. Please make your answer beginner friendly.

Here's my mint function:

```
function mintNFT(uint256 _count) public payable {
        uint256 totalSupply = totalSupply();

        require(isSaleActive, "Sale is not active" );
        require(_count > 0 && _count < MAX_TOKENS_PER_PURCHASE + 1, "Exceeds maximum tokens you can purchase in a single transaction");
        require(totalSupply + _count < MAX_TOKENS + 1, "Exceeds available NFTs");
        require(msg.value >= price * _count, "Ether value sent is not correct");
        
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _count; i++){
                _safeMint(msg.sender, totalSupply + i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this (Explained in comments if it is needed):

```
//Declare a variable to counter mint
uint256 mintCounter;

//I write the part you want, it is not all
function mintNFT(uint256 _count) public payable{
  mintCounter ++;
  
  //Part below needs some fixation
  require(msg.value >= price * (1 + (mintCount / 2000)), "Ether value sent is not correct");
}
```

That is it. If `minCount` is 1999, `(mintCount / 2000)` will be `0` so first 1999 mints will cost just 1x `price`